# Tools to migrate MongoDB to PostgreSQL

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, database-migration

I want to migrate mongoDB to PostgreSQL database.

Looking for a reliable open-source tool to carry out the migration. Have checked on MoSQL but the tool has not been updated for the last 4 years.

Comment: use can use `stitchdata` https://www.stitchdata.com/integrations/mongodb/postgresql/?utm_source=topostgres.com&utm_medium=microsite-referral&utm_campaign=microsite-referral+mongodb-topostgres.com

Comment: Thanks Manjeet. But, stitchdata is an enterprise solution. I was looking for an open-source tool.